# Create a list of Image types in Racket

Tags: image, list, racket

I am trying to create a scene with multiple images of the same type on that scene. I know how to create an image however, I need to create many images based on an arbitrary value 'n'. I believe the best way to accomplish this is through the function "(place-images images posn scene)". I understand how to accomplish the list of integer values for the second parameter 'posn' by doing "(build-list INT_VALUE values) however, I cant seem to figure out the proper way to create a list of images. Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

```
> (require 2htdp/image)
> (build-list 5 (λ (n) (circle 10 "solid" "red")))
```

[image]